# trim null character when opening in less

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a 10MB files that have ASCII text, but end with null characters.
I use `cat myfile | tr -d '\000' | less` to strip those null characters.

Looking for a way to do it automatically via `$LESSOPEN` or `lessopen.sh`.
I've tried adding in the `lessopen.sh`:

```
    if grep -q -Pa '\x00' $1; then
            tr -d '\000' $1
    fi
```

And `export LESSOPEN='| tr -d "\000" | lesspipe.sh %s'`

Neither works.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
# lessopen.sh
# Use: lesopen.sh FILE

# Parameter must be a readable file
[ ! -r "$1" ] && { echo "File '$1' doesn't exist or cannot be read!">&2; exit 1; }

tr -d '\000' < "$1"  | less
```

**EDIT**

If the script is meant to be used for reading also from `stdin`, then this version will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# lessopen.sh - deletes all null bytes (0x00) and executes less command with result
# Use: 
#   $ lessopen.sh FILE
#   $ lessopen.sh < FILE
#   $ cmd | lessopen.sh

INPUT="$1"
if [ -n "$INPUT" ];then
    # Parameter must be a readable file
    [ ! -r "$INPUT" ] && { echo "File '$INPUT' doesn't exist or cannot be read!">&2; exit 1; }
    tr -d '\000' < "$INPUT"  | less
else
    tr -d '\000' | less
fi
```

Comment: Works well when I open the file using only less (e.g. `less myfile`). But doesn't work when I pipe it through less (e.g. `cat myfile | less`)

Comment: If you mean `lessopen.sh myfile` and `cat myfile | lessopen.sh`, then the script has to be prepared to read from `stdin`, which my initial version is not. See my answer, I altered it to accept `stdin` as input too.